# Add variable value for a specific variable but in another class

Tags: python, object, data-structures

I have two classes, ClassA and ClassB, that both have variables var1 and var2. In ClassA, var1 is initialized to 1 and var2 is initialized to 2. ClassB inherits from ClassA. I want to be able to define/set the value of var1 in ClassB using the value of var1 from ClassA. Is there a way to do this in Python, similar to the set method used in Java?

Comment: Even if you did change the value of the `var1` **attribute of** `object1`, which is an **instance of** `ClassA` (it is important both to use proper terminology, and to actually understand how classes work) - why would that change the value of `sum`, which was **already computed** and is now *just a perfectly ordinary integer, which has no relationship to `object1` or to anything else*? You appear to be very confused in general, and my advice is to try to follow a Python tutorial from the start, and make sure you learn the fundamentals in order.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it's not about sum at all. The print command has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: would write a sample code for me with the write terminology?

Comment: I can't understand. When you run the code, what do you think should happen, that is different from what is already happening? Why do you believe there is a problem? "I want to give the value "1" in ClassB!" Why do you think this is not already happening?

Comment: You assign directly to `class_a.var1`. If you mean, assigning to `object2.var1` changes the value of `object1.var1`, you need to make `ClassB.var1` a property whose setter makes the direct assignment.

Comment: @chepner yes I mean to "assigning to object2.var1 changes the value of object1.var1" Would you write a sample code for it please? (or change the sample code I have and post it as an answer and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClassB` inherits `ClassA`, so it will have `var1` if you call `ClassA` `__init__`. You need to do it from `ClassB` `__init__` instead of creating seperate object and sending it as value

```
class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

object2 = ClassB()
print(object2.var1) # 1
```